# Datatables with mongo db issue

Tags: php, mongodb, datatables

Hello There i'm using Laravel 5.7.26 with mongo db.
I want to fetch the products details from mongo db and load into Data tables,my mongo db contains 2081 products.
Sometimes it will load and some times it gives an an error `DataTables warning: table id=ProductTables - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7`

---

### This is my Product.Js file

`

```
/**
 * @author Prakash Vaghela<prakashvaghela700@gmail.com>
 * @description this function will fatch the data from mongo db using Ajax and dynamically
 * append row to datatables
 * @returns {Boolean}
 */
function initializeTable() {

    if (tableDataTable) {
        return false;
    }

    tableDataTable = $table.on('preXhr.dt', function (e, settings, data) {
//        showLoading("loading data...");
    }).on('draw.dt', function () {
//        hideLoading();
    }).DataTable({
        processing: true,
        "language": {
            "processing": "Hang on. Waiting for response..." //add a loading image,simply putting <img src="loader.gif" /> tag.
        },
        serverSide: true,
        pageLength: 5,
        ajax: {
            url: window.loadProducts,
            type: 'post',
            data: function (d) {
                d._token = token;
                d.vendorKeyword = vendorKeyword;
                d.productTypeKeyword = productTypeKeyword;
                return d;
            },
        },
        columnDefs: [
            {
                name: "pid",
                data: "pid",
                className: "text-center",
                targets: [0],
                visible: true,
                render: function (data, type, row, meta) {

                    var return_div = $("<div class='table-data-design '>");
                    var productBox = $(".product-dropDown").clone();
                    productBox.removeClass("product-dropDown");
                    productBox.addClass("parentDiv");
                    productBox.attr("data-pid", row.pid);
                    productBox.find("#parentImage").attr("src", row.img);
                    productBox.find(".parent-titleName").html(row.title);
                    var variants = row.variants;
                    $.each(variants, function (key, value) {
                        var childBox = $(".child-box-container").clone();
                        childBox.show();
                        childBox.removeClass("child-box-container");
                        childBox.attr("data-variantPid", value.id)
                        childBox.addClass("variant");
                        childBox.find("#childImage").attr("src", value.img);
                        childBox.find(".child-titleName").html(value.title);
                        childBox.find(".variant-price").html(value.price);
                        var indexInArray = isSelectedList.indexOf(value.id);
                        if (indexInArray > -1) {
                            childBox.css({"background-color": "#4998f2"});
                            childBox.attr("isSelected", "1");
                        }
                        productBox.append(childBox);
                    });
                    productBox.show();
                    return_div.append(productBox);
                    return return_div.html();
                },
            },
            {
                name: "title",
                data: "title",
                className: "text-center",
                targets: [1],
                visible: false,
                render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    var return_div = $("<div class='table-data-design '>");
                    return_div.append(data);
                    return return_div.html();
                }
            },
            {
                name: "vendor",
                data: "vendor",
                className: "text-center",
                targets: [2],
                visible: false,
                render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    var return_div = $("<div class='table-data-design '>");
                    return_div.append(data);
                    return return_div.html();
                }
            },
            {
                name: "type",
                data: "type",
                className: "text-center",
                targets: [3],
                visible: false,
                render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    var return_div = $("<div class='table-data-design '>");
                    return_div.append(data);
                    return return_div.html();
                }
            },
        ]
    });
}
/**
 * @author Prakash Vaghela<prakashvaghela700@gmail.com>
 * @description this method will triggers when user change the dropdown list
 * based on selected value data tables fatch vendors products only from db
 */
$(document).on("change", "#selectVendor", function () {

    vendorKeyword = $("#selectVendor option:selected").val();
    tableDataTable.ajax.reload();
});
/**
 * @author Prakash Vaghela<prakashvaghela700@gmail.com>
 * @description this method will triggers when user change the dropdown list
 * based on selected value data tables fatch products type only from db
 */
$(document).on("change", "#selectProductType", function () {

    productTypeKeyword = $("#selectProductType option:selected").val();
    tableDataTable.ajax.reload();
});
```

---

### Html File which contains table to dynamically popoulate via datatables

```
@extends('layout.app')
@section('content')

<div class="Polaris-Stack__Item">
                                    <div>
                                        <table id="ProductTables" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" style="width:100%">

                                            <thead>
                                            <th>Products</th>
                                            <th>title</th>
                                            <th>vendor</th>
                                            <th>type</th>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>

                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
@csrf
@stop
@section('js')
<script src="{{asset('js/app/manageProduct.js')}}?t=<?php echo time(); ?>"></script>
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
<script>
     window.updateSubscribeSettings = "{{url("updateSubscribeSettings")}}";
     window.syncProduct = "{{url("syncProduct")}}";
     window.loadProducts = "{{url("loadProducts")}}";
     window.loadVendorAndProductList = "{{url("loadVendorAndProductList")}}";
     window.filterProduct = "{{url("filterProduct")}}";
</script>
@stop
```

---

### ProductMongoController.php which fatch the data from mongodb

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Log;
use DB;
use Auth;
use Auth\User;
use Pimlie\DataTables\MongodbDataTable;

class ProductMongoController extends Controller {
/**
     * @author Prakash Vaghela<prakashvaghela700@gmail.com>
     * @description This method will fatch the products from mongo db 
     * @param Request $request
     * @return \Exception
     */
    public function loadProducts(Request $request) {
        $retData = new \stdClass();

        $vendorKeyword = $request->vendorKeyword;
        $productTypeKeyword = $request->productTypeKeyword;
        $shopid = Auth::user()->id;

        try {
            if ($vendorKeyword && $productTypeKeyword) {
                $datatables = datatables(DB::connection('mongodb')
                                ->collection('product_' . $shopid)
                                ->where("vendor", "=", $vendorKeyword)
                                ->where("type", "=", $productTypeKeyword)
                                ->get());
            } else if ($vendorKeyword) {
                $datatables = datatables(DB::connection('mongodb')
                                ->collection('product_' . $shopid)
                                ->where("vendor", "=", $vendorKeyword)
                                ->get());
            } else if ($productTypeKeyword) {
                $datatables = datatables(DB::connection('mongodb')
                                ->collection('product_' . $shopid)
                                ->where("type", "=", $productTypeKeyword)
                                ->get());
            } else {
                $datatables = datatables(DB::connection('mongodb')
                                ->collection('product_' . $shopid)
                                ->get());
            }
            return $datatables->toJson();
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            return $ex;
        }
    }
  }
```

---

### Web.php this files which contains the routes

```
Route::post('/loadProducts', 'ProductMongoController@loadProducts');
```

---

### Output without Error

### [image]

### Output with Error

[image]